# webservice XML encoding error

Tags: php, xml, web-services

Following is the error i get,
 This page contains the following errors:

> error on line 1 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
>   error on line 1 at column 1: Encoding error

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Following is the code,

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['itemno'])) {
    $number_of_posts = isset($_GET['number']) ? intval($_GET['number']) : 20;
    $format          = strtolower($_GET['format']) == 'json' ? 'json' : 'xml';
    $user_id         = intval($_GET['itemno']);
    /* connect to mysql database */
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Can not connect to the Database');
    mysql_select_db('test', $link) or die('Can not select the Database');
    /* select records from the database */
    $query = "SELECT qty, price FROM postatusinfo WHERE itemno = $user_id";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die('Errant query:  ' . $query);
    /* create array of the records */
    $posts = array();
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        while ($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $posts[] = array('post' => $post);
        }
    }
    /* output in required format */
    if ($format == 'json') {
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array('posts' => $posts));
    } else {
        header('Content-type: text/xml');
        echo '<posts>';
        foreach ($posts as $index => $post) {
            if (is_array($post)) {
                foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
                    echo '<', $key, '>';
                    if (is_array($value)) {
                        foreach ($value as $tag => $val) {
                            echo '<', $tag, '>', htmlentities($val), '</', $tag, '>';
                        }
                    }
                    echo '</', $key, '>';
                }
            }
        }
        echo '</posts>';
    }
    /* close database connection */
    @mysql_close($link);
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the text output itself, it would be impossible to know for sure what is happening here. (*earlier edit:* The PHP code you have used in your question was invalid, I fixed it. Please double check before you post code here. Also indent it properly.) Also the error is with XML, not with JSON - at least as far as I know these error messages.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Ya i too found the error in XML

Comment: You should leave some info in form of a comment then what caused your issue so if somebody else finds your question here can at least have a hint what helped you. It's not really an answer, but sharing a comment about how you solved it does not hurt.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is problem with file encoding, especially with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Try to open with editor which show BOM (like notepad++) and then try to remove it.